# Why is Chrome caching 302 redirect even though proper cache-control headers are set?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, drupal-7, browser-cache, http-status-code-302

I have custom page in Drupal 7 to handle 403 and 404 requests which redirects the user to my applications homepage. I have set an error message to display after redirection. The issue is that when an invalid URL is requested frequently, the error is not displayed/set because chrome is caching my redirect page. When I try this on other browsers the error message is set on every request.
To counter this I have set the Cache-Control header to 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' and Expires header to 0. I also tried setting the above headers in my htaccess file. Still the issue persists. I need a solution such that I can stop my redirect caching

Answer (score 0):

I assume that basically you want to display error whenever 403 and 404 request made to your application and due to caching you are unable to display error message all the time.

What you can do is when first time 403/404 request made to your app, store it to sessions and next time again same request made to your app then you can find it in session variable. if found then display errors.

The above solution does not deal with the cache but might help you to achieve your requirements.

Thanks :)